# how do i apply the maas bug fix?

Tags: juju, maas

i am having this bug on my 12.03 ubuntu, https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1204507
But i dont know how to apply the bug fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is only in saucy.  The main archive will contain the fixed package soon, or you can use the daily PPA if desperate.

```
sudo add-apt-repository lp:~maas-maintainers/dailybuilds
```